# How to separate out the required fields from arrays on objects in mongo dB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mern

I don't know how to query the nested documents and filter out those fields which have

**`"status": "Pending"`**

Here's my sample document:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63fa3203ef0dcc2ef8e163d1"
  },
  "username": "M. Irtaza Ghaffar",
  "email": "irtazaghaffar@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2b$10$TB/EfVGXogTGNr6DKrbACebpPiiFx8yV0f84OctM4b9ZR9rCP5I/G",
  "__v": 0,
  "todos": [
    {
      "title": "1",
      "desc": "1",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2014-02-10T10:50:42.389Z"
      },
      "status": "Completed",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63fa5bb19934bc58a0d674ed"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-02-25T19:04:17.425Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "2",
      "desc": "2",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2014-02-10T10:50:42.389Z"
      },
      "status": "Completed",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63fa6673a2070da9679e0c38"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-02-25T19:50:11.256Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "3",
      "desc": "3",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-09T21:19:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffc172fe6afb42ca9872ed"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:19:46.352Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "4",
      "desc": "4",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-17T21:28:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffc363fe6afb42ca987317"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:28:03.388Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "5",
      "desc": "5",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-17T21:28:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffc391fe6afb42ca987320"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:28:49.418Z"
      }
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

The answer required is:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63fa3203ef0dcc2ef8e163d1"
  },
  "username": "M. Irtaza Ghaffar",
  "email": "irtazaghaffar@gmail.com",
  "password": "$2b$10$TB/EfVGXogTGNr6DKrbACebpPiiFx8yV0f84OctM4b9ZR9rCP5I/G",
  "__v": 0,
  "todos": [
    {
      "title": "3",
      "desc": "3",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-09T21:19:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffc172fe6afb42ca9872ed"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:19:46.352Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "3",
      "desc": "3",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:26:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffc315fe6afb42ca9872f5"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:26:45.524Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "3",
      "desc": "3",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:26:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffc33ffe6afb42ca9872fa"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:27:27.713Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "3",
      "desc": "3",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:26:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffc34ffe6afb42ca987307"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:27:43.120Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "4",
      "desc": "4",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-17T21:28:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffc363fe6afb42ca987317"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:28:03.388Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "5",
      "desc": "5",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-17T21:28:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffc391fe6afb42ca987320"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T21:28:49.418Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "100",
      "desc": "100",
      "end": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T22:10:00Z"
      },
      "status": "Pending",
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "63ffcd7048fab18307faf719"
      },
      "start": {
        "$date": "2023-03-01T22:10:56.937Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here, you can see that there are no fields having **"status": "Pending"**

Here are my tried Queries but they only respond back those documents that have at least one **"status": "Pending"**

```js
const getPendingTodos = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, status } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await userModel
      .aggregate([
        { $match: { "todos.status": "Pending" } },
        { $project: { index: { $indexOfArray: [ "$todos.status", "Pending" ] } } }
      ])
      .then();
    res.status(200).json({
      loggedIn: true,
      todos: user[0].todos,
    });
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(200).json({
      loggedIn: false,
    });
  }
};
```

```js
const getPendingTodos = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, status } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await userModel
      .find({
        email: email,
        "todos.status": "Pending"
      })
      .then();
    res.status(200).json({
      loggedIn: true,
      todos: user[0].todos,
    });
  } catch (error) 
      res.status(200).json({ loggedIn: false });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

if you only need to filter the item with `status = pending`

than you can remove the operation `$match` and use `$filter`
it would be:

```
const user = await userModel.aggregate([
  //{ $match: { "todos.status": "Pending" } }, replace with email instead
  { $match: { email: "example@email.em" } }
  {
    $project: {
      items: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$todos",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$todos.status",
              "Pending"
            ]
          },
          as: "todos"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/opRcUcdYVz9)

Comment: Why `$gte` instead of `$eq`?

Comment: you are right, it was typo. sorry about that.